# How to create and use responsive themes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm getting `MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.` when trying to access MediaQuery from `MaterialApp`:

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: getTheme(MediaQuery.of(context)),
  home: new Container(),
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `builder` of `MaterialApp` instead.  So that you can use `MediaQuery` instantiated by `MatetialApp` inside your `Theme`.

```
new MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return new Theme(
      data: getTheme(MediaQuery.of(context)),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  home: new ChatScreen(),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: getTheme(new MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window)),
      home: new Container(),
    );
```

Thanks Günter :)

Comment: I'd use `builder` property instead

Comment: Can you post a reply with an example?