# How to set MediaQuery textScaleFactor of fontSize in MaterialApp theme

Tags: flutter

I want to set MediaQuery inside the MaterialApp Theme so that in case user changes the setting the FontSize respects the user settings.

I tried creating the final curlScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor; 
and used accordingly set the fontSize: 20 * curlScale inside the MaterialApp 
but getting error as "MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery."
How can I solve this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final curlScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
    return MaterialApp(

      title: 'Expense Tracker App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
        accentColor: Colors.limeAccent,
        fontFamily: 'QuickSand',
        errorColor: Colors.red,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
          title: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Open Sans', fontSize: 16 * curlScale),
          button: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),


          )
          )
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
```

When the user changes the font settings the Fontsize should respects the user settings.

Comment: I see we've been working on the same tutorial ;) Max should have covered this topic with a bit more detail

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using this:
**MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context)**

E.g:

```
textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                title: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  fontSize: 18 * MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context), 
                ),
```

According to the documentation this method

> Returns textScaleFactor for the nearest MediaQuery ancestor or 1.0, if no such ancestor exists.

Docs:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/textScaleFactor.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery/textScaleFactorOf.html

Comment: `textScaleFactorOf` is deprecated https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/deprecate-textscalefactor?gclid=Cj0KCQiAj_CrBhD-ARIsAIiMxT9iKZ64HaAYrTVRx8uXDc2FNmnckphKgXG-WMbRv6Tr4_zeCwlulQ4aAoEiEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

In widget where you want to apply font

```
Text(
'My font size is 24px o',
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.cyanAccent,
fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(24),
)),
```

Here is main login to scale font

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenUtil {
static ScreenUtil instance = new ScreenUtil();

double width;
double height;
bool allowFontScaling;

static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
static double _screenWidth;
static double _screenHeight;
static double _pixelRatio;
static double _statusBarHeight;

static double _bottomBarHeight;

static double _textScaleFactor;

ScreenUtil({
    this.width = 1080,
    this.height = 1920,
    this.allowFontScaling = false,
});

static ScreenUtil getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

void init(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    _mediaQueryData = mediaQuery;
    _pixelRatio = mediaQuery.devicePixelRatio;
    _screenWidth = mediaQuery.size.width;
    _screenHeight = mediaQuery.size.height;
    _statusBarHeight = mediaQuery.padding.top;
    bottomBarHeight = mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;
    _textScaleFactor = mediaQuery.textScaleFactor;
}

static MediaQueryData get mediaQueryData => _mediaQueryData;
static double get textScaleFactory => _textScaleFactor;
static double get pixelRatio => _pixelRatio;
static double get screenWidthDp => _screenWidth;
static double get screenHeightDp => _screenHeight;
static double get screenWidth => screenWidth * pixelRatio;
static double get screenHeight => screenHeight * pixelRatio;
static double get statusBarHeight => _statusBarHeight;
static double get bottomBarHeight => _bottomBarHeight;
get scaleWidth => _screenWidth / instance.width;
get scaleHeight => _screenHeight / instance.height;
setWidth(double width) => width * scaleWidth;
setHeight(double height) => height * scaleHeight;
setSp(double fontSize) {
print("Scale 10 ${setWidth(fontSize)}");
print("Scale 12 ${ _textScaleFactor}");
print("Scale 11 ${setWidth(fontSize) / _textScaleFactor}");
return allowFontScaling
? setWidth(fontSize)
: setWidth(fontSize) / _textScaleFactor;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use inside the MaterialApp so that I can globally define the fontsize so final curlScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor can't be done?

Comment: @divyadave you can set it in text theme that will apply on all over the app.

Comment: bottomBarHeight is mistook. you forgot _

Answer (score 0):

As explained here: [How to create and use responsive themes in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891969/how-to-create-and-use-responsive-themes-in-flutter)

You should use the builder property.

```
return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Expense Tracker App',
    builder: (ctx, child) {
      return Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
              accentColor: Colors.limeAccent,
              fontFamily: 'QuickSand',
              errorColor: Colors.red,
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                  textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                        headline1: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                            fontSize:
                                16 * MediaQuery.of(ctx).textScaleFactor),
                        button: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ))),
          child: child);
    },
    home: HomePage(),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it globally like this

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
  child: MediaQuery(
    child: widget as Widget,
    data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor:1.0),
    ),
))
```

Then every fontSize will be multiplied by the textScaleFactor