# Can I scale a complete flutter app when the resolution is too high for the screen dimensions?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a Zebra CC600 running Android Oreo. https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/spec-sheets/interactive-kiosks/cc600.html

Screen resolution: 1280x720, Screen size: 5inch

The problem is that everything is way too small. Is there a way with Flutter, to scale the whole app?

[image: CC600 Screenshot]

[image: default flutter project]

[image: CC600 vs TC51]

I did try MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context)

[How to set MediaQuery textScaleFactor of fontSize in MaterialApp theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337154/how-to-set-mediaquery-textscalefactor-of-fontsize-in-materialapp-theme?rq=1)

But that only sizes the text, but not everything else.

The third photo compares a TC51(top) to the CC600(bottom). The letters of the CC600 are barely readable. I think that the device was not configured correctly by the manufacturer. This is the reason I would like to scale the whole app.

Comment: if you hard code dimensions everywhere, there is no way to scale it up. Otherwise you can easily do by checking the available screen space using MediaQuery or LayoutBuilder

Comment: I have not hardcoded the dimensions anywhere.

Comment: then what makes you in trouble?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the default Flutter app on the device. Everything is default way too small.

Comment: I agree with you. But why don't you try to use MediaQuery/ LayoutBuilder to calculate dynamic size for every widget?

Comment: for example, if the appbar height is 56.0 for 5.0 inch phone, use 72.0 or something larger for a 10.0 inch phone.

Comment: The only device that this app is going to run on is this CC600, so it is even possible to set all dimensions manually. But it would be nice if there was some root scale factor. Now I have to find out myself which parts are too small.

Comment: If you scale everything, would not it look too ugly?

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter app actually looks completely normal. It's scaled to the device's DPI.

BUT if you want to scale the app, here's my advice. (What we do for our production apps, be aware that some steps in the main are skipped on the release..)

The reason we use a different technique is that it's far easier and less messy than the MediaQuery / LayoutBuilder solution (which is awful in my opinion)

The easy solution

In the main.dart put this at the top, before the class so it's globally available

```
/// Used to scale smaller devices.
/// Font and sizes. Not used everywhere. Used for tweaking smaller device.
double deviceScale = 1.0;
```

Make this function somewhere

```
setDeviceScaler() {
    // You can tweak this so scale for different devices. For example tiny iPhone SE can by super smaller or big :-)
    double deviceHeightInPoints = (window.physicalSize.height / window.devicePixelRatio);
    if (deviceHeightInPoints < 700.0) {
      deviceScale = 0.90;
    }
    if (deviceHeightInPoints < 600.0) {
      deviceScale = 0.80;
    }
    print('Device scale: ' + deviceScale.toString());
  }
```

Inside your main app class add this:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  setDeviceScaler();
}
```

Also, add this to your first screen. Because sometimes the `window.devicePixelRatio` is not initialized properly until the first scaffold widget. You may need to add `setDeviceScaler()` inside those first screen inits.

Now, anywhere you set TextStyles or Widget dimensions simply call `* deviceScale`

```
TextStyle titleStyle({bool darkText = false}) {
  return TextStyle(
    color: darkText ? AppColors.darkFont : AppColors.lightFont,
    fontSize: 20 * deviceScale,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @oliver-dixon, thanks for your help. I've added a photo, which compares two devices. Both have standard font-size/resolution settings. In my opinion, there is clearly something wrong with the CC600. But I agree, not with the Flutter app itself as it sizes itself according to the OS as expected. As I understand from your answer, there is no magic bullet that lets you scale the app as a whole, but manual tweaks to individual texts and widgets.