# Cant use MediaQuery.of(context) for Themes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am trying to create several `TextTheme` and change the fonts sizes using `MediaQuery.of(context)` based on this article:

[Flutter — Effectively scale UI according to different screen sizes](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a)

But I am getting this error:

> MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.

I know based on this post: [Flutter Error: MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214338/flutter-error-mediaquery-of-called-with-a-context-that-does-not-contain-a-med)

I should use `MediaQuery` on my HomePage but then I cannot create themes using `MediaQuery` then?

Here is my code:

```
  child:
    MaterialApp(
            theme: ThemeData(
                /// TextFields Handlers transparent
                textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.transparent,
                pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(
                  builders: <TargetPlatform, PageTransitionsBuilder>{
                    TargetPlatform.android: ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder(),
                  },
                ),
                textTheme: TextTheme(
                  /// Pages Titles
                  headline1: textTheme(
                    fontSize: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100) * 1.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: Globals.allColors['celeste'],
                  ),
                  headline2: textTheme(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Globals.allColors['cetaceanBlue']),
                      ...
```

The error is at:

```
(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100) * 1.5,
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/49891969/10157127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot create your material theme with values retrieved from Mediaquery. You set 'default' font size, etc. in your material app theme data. Then in your home page build method you call Mediaquery and modify your font size for that page if necessary.

Comment: That is a shame, it would be useful to resize the fonts based on each device resolution, using `themes` instead of changing them with `.copyWith`  all over the code. Thanks for your answer Graham

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your entire homepage in a builder widget.

Comment: Got the same error trying to use `Builder` Widget above `MaterialApp`, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do this like a one-off kind of thing. You could save your text themes in a `themes.dart` file or something like that..and then subsequently, you could have a loading page, where you make a `MediaQuery` and calculate your theme values there.

I think you might have to run `setState` after that, maybe not, because when you navigate to your home screen from there, the values of the theme would have updated.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaQuery` needs the `MaterialApp` widget as an ancestor, you can't use it when constructing the `MaterialApp` itself. A workaround is not using the `theme` property but wrapping the descendants with a `Theme` widget using the `builder` property. It will have the `MaterialApp` as an ancestor so you can use `MediaQuery` there.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        // your theme
        // can use e.g. MediaQuery.of(context).size.width here
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  home: SomeScreen(),
  // etc, no theme here
)
```